# Calcular a soma dos valores de uma matriz e armazena-la na primeira posição disponível de um vetor

Tags: c

Estou com problemas no ciclo que armazena o valor da variável `aux` na primeira posição vazia do vetor `re` e não consigo ver onde está meu erro. O valor que está sendo armazenado não é o valor de aux, e sim, o valor `-842150451`

```
    int l = 0, c = 0, o = 0, aux = 0;
    int** mat = 0, *re = 0, reaux = 0;

    printf("Ordem da matriz quadrada:\n>");
    scanf_s("%i", &o);
    l = o;
    c = o;

    reaux = l + c + 2;
    re = malloc(sizeof(int*) * reaux);

    //soma colunas
    //ciclo para somar os valores
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            aux += mat[i][j];
        }

    }
    //ciclo para armazenar no primeiro slot vazio
    for (int k = 0; k < (l + c) - 1; k++) {
        if (re[k] == 0) {
            re[k] = aux;
            aux = 0;

        }
    }
    //ciclo para que caso a soma da coluna seja diferente da soma da coluna anterior a variável "cl" receba 1
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        if ((int)i != 0 && re[(int)i] != re[(int)i - 1]) {
            cl = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Aqui: re = malloc(sizeof(int*) * reaux); não deveria ser sizeof(int) e não sizeof(int*)? Se você não inicializou seu array re por qual motivo você testa se o conteúdo é zero?

Comment: Eu inicializei o array quando declarei ```*re = 0,```, porém mudei a linha do malloc para (int) como voce sugeriu e o resultado foi o mesmo: ```-842150451```.

Comment: Você não inicializou o array com zero, você atribuiu zero ao ponteiro re e depois disso você atribuiu a re o endereço da área alocada sobrepondo o zero.

Comment: E como eu corrijo isso?

Comment: Após alocar seu array varra todas as suas posições alocadas atribuindo zero a cada posição.

Comment: Também falta alocar sua matriz mat. Aloque um array de ponteiros (linhas) e cada um desses ponteiros aponte para uma área alocada de inteiros (colunas).